# react native - Google Play Console report crash "x4.c"

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I have an app writing by React Native, and available on Google Play. There are some crashes reported by Play Console.

However, I have no clues after reading the crash report.

I also do some research about the `x4.c` but haven't found a fix for it.

## General:

[image]

## Issue 1:

[image]

## Issue 2:

[image]

## Issue 3:

[image]

## Issue 4:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Many thanks!